# Rotate a UIView in 2D, not 3D

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics

When I use either of the following pieces of code, the button rotates in 3D rather than 2D (flat against the screen). How can I avoid the 3D behavior? Here's what the button looks like during the rotation:

[image]

```
CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationTransform, (offset/(180.0 * M_PI)));
    button.transform = rotationTransform;
```

.

```
    button.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, (offset/(180.0 * M_PI)));
```

.

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(offset/(180.0 * M_PI));
```

Comment: CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(offset/(180.0*M_PI); The other concat the matrix, (is weir that it doens't work)

Comment: I tried that, and the rotation is still 3D.

Comment: Didn't you modified the backing layer, or some factor of the transformation matrix, such as the m34 value? m34 add a sort of perspective is the punto di fuga (can't find any translation in english, found vanishing point)

Comment: @Stavash the correct translation should be "vanishing point" found un wiki. I'm thinking about that because the button seems to has a sort of perspective, and seems to be rotate on another avis. That' why I'm asking if the app is playing witn layers.

Comment: @Andrea Understood. It probably is playing with the layers - this should be pretty straightforward. I would recommend taking this issue to a side project that has only this button and the code that's supposed to rotate it.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the answer from an Apple employee:

> When you set a transform the frame becomes less well-defined, to the
>   point that you should no longer use it to size or position a view. Try
>   using the center property instead, your probably not getting a 3D
>   rotation, but a distortion due to the compounding effect of setting
>   the frame and trnsform.

Comment: +1. That wouldn't be surprising — the documentation is explicit that if `transform` is not uniform then the `frame` property becomes undefined. If you change both in an animation block then every frame Core Animation will set the one then set the other. It doesn't matter which way round it does it, at some point you're going to try to adjust the undefined value, producing undefined results.

Comment: Problem finally solved, frustration ended. With an 8 year old answer. This is why I love stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem which is really annoying, and I got it settled at last, though still have no idea why.

I got unexpected 3D rotations when I tried to perform a 2D rotation ***in "viewDidLayoutSubviews" method*** with

```
double radius = (degree / 180.0) * M_PI;
uiImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radius);
```

**My solution is to perform transforming elsewhere other than "viewDidLayoutSubviews" and it is working perfectly.**

Interestingly, when the annoying 3D rotation happens, and I keep orienting my iPhone for a while, the 3D rotation will disappear suddenly and 2D rotation will come back and take the place, but the image stays at a distorted shape. I guess maybe iOS is doing some internal transforming in "viewDidLayoutSubviews" and things get messed up if we impose additional transforming on it. However, my guess cannot explain why it disappears after a while. I also tried to NSLog the members of "uiImageView.transform", say, "a, b, c, d, tx, ty" in "viewDidLayoutSubviews" but got no clue.

**SOLUTION: Check your code to see if you are performing the rotation in "viewDidLayoutSubviews" or some similar method, and if yes, try to move it out to elsewhere and cross fingers.**